# WordPress Updated: "Plugin not found" message when check for changelog

Tags: wordpress

Recently I am seeing often (not always) this message when there is a plugin update and I click to the new version link to see the changelog:

[Wordpress update message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qHIh.png)

I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please make sure if plugin directory name(s) aren't with any space before or after? Slight changes in directory or plugin name brings this error usually.

Comment: Do you mean from wp-content/plugins/ directory? Nope, all plugin folder names are okay. This issue is more and more frequent with several (not all) plugins... Very strange